# How do I modify jsonb in place, adding keys and moving values to aid querying later

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I've got the following hypothetical data items in my postgres db, table: user_tracking

```
id: 210 
date: 2022-02-06 17:05:44.000 +0600 
item_json: {"MouseDown": "202,2525"}

id: 212 
date: 2022-02-06 17:05:46.000 +0600 
item_json: {"MouseUp": "299,2530"}
```

The problem is that I've made a mistake with how I've put the data in the jsonb, what I actually want is:

```
id: 210 
date: 2022-02-06 17:05:44.000 +0600 
item_json: {"action": "MouseDown", "value": "202,2525"}

id: 212 
date: 2022-02-06 17:05:46.000 +0600 
item_json: {"action": "MouseUp", "value": "299,2530"}
```

I'm trying to work out how to modify the data that is there, row by row, to get the result as I realised that this isn't an optimal queryable format otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deconstruct the JSONB object into a table using `jsonb_each`, and construct a new one using `jsonb_build_object`. ([Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html))

```
UPDATE user_tracking SET item_json = (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'action', key,
    'value', value
  )
  FROM jsonb_each(item_json)
);
```

(Make sure you back up your table before any big changes like this, just in case.)

Comment: in order to use that, don't I need a WHERE clause, won't it complain about more than one row returned otherwise?

Comment: No, the `SELECT` is a subquery executing for each row separately, where `item_json` is from that row. Also, it only has one row, since the JSONB only has one key/value pair. Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wGPeZD5vUEuoTpfbY2KLg7/0

Comment: weird, i run through your example fine, i even implemented it on my db... but when I push it out to the much larger production db (that doesn't match the above design - but does have a column with jsonb). That is when it complains about the more than one row returned by subquery.

Comment: Then I suppose you have rows where a single JSONB has multiple key/value pairs, like `'{"MouseDown": "202,2525", "MouseUp": "299,2530"}'::jsonb`. You have not included such examples in the question, nor what you want to be done in such cases, so my answer does not cover them.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Can I add a filter to this for only those items with a single key value pair then?

Comment: Sure. You can e.g. add `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jsonb_object_keys(item_json)) = 1` to the end in order to only update the rows with a single key/value pair, or you can put `LIMIT 1` at the end of the inner `SELECT` to pick just one of the key/value pairs.